# Differentiable, Parametrized Curve for Trace $y = |x|$

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves

my professor gave practice problems for an upcoming midterm, and one is to find a differentiable parametrized curve with trace $y = |x|$ with $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

My thinking is that I should find a parametrization with $\alpha'(0) = (0,0)$ and of course $x = -y, x = y$ for negative and positive $x$ respectively, however I cannot think of such a curve. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Suggestion: Pick your favorite smooth, increasing function $f$ that satisfies $f'(0) = 0$, and put $x = f(t)$, $y = |f(t)|$. (For extra fun, see how smooth you can make the parametrization.)

Comment: Aha, so I can simply take $|t^3|$ to be $y$, I did not think to use absolute value on a function, thank you. What do you mean by how smooth exactly?

Comment: If you pick a suitable $f$, you can get a $C^{\infty}$ parametrization. :) That's not necessary from your problem statement, but is worth knowing: Smoothness of a mapping doesn't of itself imply "local smoothness" of the image; you need something like regularity (injectivity of the derivative at each point). Examples such as the [cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) or [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid) curves show that a _real-analytic_ mapping can have an image with cusps.