# What does guarantee that the image of a mapping is smooth ($C^{\infty}$)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In a question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645378/differentiable-parametrized-curve-for-trace-y-x) about finding a differentiable parametrized curve with trace $y=|x|$, there is the following comment by Andrew D. Hwang "Smoothness of a mapping doesn't of itself imply local smoothness of the image". He claims that one needs *something* like regularity (injectivity of the derivative at each point). My question is: what is the exact necessary and sufficient condition for the image of a mapping to be smooth?

I would be grateful if one could provide an answer as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a sufficient **and necessary** condition${}^1$: one can always construct an example of a function which doesn't satisfy the conditions but whose image is smooth. The most often used sufficient condition is:

> Let $M,N$ be smooth maniolds. Suppose $f:M\to N$ is smooth. Let $m\in M$. If
>   $$Df_m:T_mM\to T_{f(m)}N$$
>   is injective, then there exists an open neighborhood $m\in U\subseteq M$ of $m$ such that $f|_U:U\to N$ is a smooth embedding. In particular, $f(U)$ is a smooth submanifold of $N$.

There are also more elaborate versions where you only ask that $Df$ has constant rank in a neighborhood of $m$, for example. But what theorem you need to use really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

---

${}^1$Well, one which is not completely tautological, at least. Of course, I could always say that a sufficient and necessary condition is that the image is smooth, but how would that help?

Comment: Thank you, Daniel Robert-Nicoud. Unfortunately, I haven't understood the notation you have used. What is $T$? What is $D$?


I am interested mainly in the cases where the image is a point or a curve in 2D or 3D, more precisely in mappings like $f:D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f:D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$. What would be the answer to my question in these three particular cases?

Comment: @DiegoS.Rodrigues $T$ denotes the tangent space, $D$ is the derivative. In the cases you describe, $Df_m$ is simply the usual derivative of $f$ at the point $m$.